# SCSS variables: How to assign a retrieved value

Tags: sass, angular-material

I have a CSS variable `--standard-backcolor` which is assigned like

`--standard-backcolor: green`

This works fine when I use it like

`background-color: var(--standard-backcolor);`

But when I retrieve the color from another instance, like Angular Material like

`--standard-backcolor: mat.get-color-from-palette($greyPalette, 900);`

it is neither retrieved from the SCSS properly. I would guess this is caused by the fact that I don't assign the value directly - more in a later way.

I've tried as well

```
$test: mat.get-color-from-palette($greyPalette, 900);
:root & {
        --standard-backcolor: $test;
...
```

Which fails as well :-/

==> How to assign the CSS variable a retrieved value to use it later?

Comment: You can't print them out like that, as `sass` does not know what you mean to there. You could be printing some perfectly valid CSS value there, anyhow. You need to escape your CSS Variable in SASS `--var: #{$sass-var};` in order to output its sass-computed value.

Comment: Thx for the hint which solved my problem already :-)